# Get total number of followers

Tags: jquery, api, instagram

I use the code below to fetch followers of my Instagram account and show profile pictures on my site. This works fine. What I also want to do is to show the total number of followers on my site and this is what I need help with.

Below is the complete code and as you can see I've tried with "data.counts.followed_by". This gives my the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'followed_by' of undefined".

How can I achieve what I want?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $access_token = '{access-token}';
    pollInstagram('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxxxx/followed-by?access_token=xxxxx&count=15');
});

function pollInstagram(next_url, count){

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: next_url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback",
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.data, function(i, item) {
                console.log(data.counts.followed_by); <-----        

                var img = '<img style="width: 18%; margin-right: 7px;" src=' + data.data[i].profile_picture + ' />';

                $('#show-images').append(img);
            });
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert("Check you internet Connection");
            $("#log").val($("#log").val() + 'Error\n');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(data)` to see the structure of the object?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Get instagram followers count with jQuery](https://snipt.net/raw/7d14f43d7457f924d3b7ad3fcf4fc470/?nice)

Comment: The link may theoretically answer the question, but [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: how link to Snipt(Automatic deploy to Heroku)[You can click the button below to automatically deploy Snipt to Heroku] can help ?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks.
I figured it out

```sql
SELECT follow_to, count(follow_to) as NUM FROM followers GROUP BY follow_to
```

Comment: This answer seems to be somewhat unrelated to the question since the only has JavaScript code without any sign of direct database interaction